# Why is setting UIScrollView.delaysContentTouches to false not necessary for UIButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm setting images for a UIButton's normal and highlighted states. However, since it's in a UIScrollView, unless I set the scroll view's `delaysContentTouches` to false, the button's highlighted state doesn't show unless the user long-presses the button.

Delaying content touches isn't ideal, since the user can't initiate a scroll gesture on top of the button.

However, it seem like somehow `UIButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted` is able to show the highlighted state immediately upon tap without the need to set `delaysContentTouches` to false. Is there a way to be using UIButton to get the same behavior for its images?

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems like `UIButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted` and `UIControl.State.highlighted` have differing criteria for what it means to be "highlighted", I ended up making a custom `UIButton` which overrides `setImage` to simply save the images in custom properties and overrides `touchesBegan`/`touchesEnded`/`touchesCancelled` to call `super.setImage` and actually set the image (only ever setting `.normal`). I'm just using `.normal` and completely ignoring `.highlighted`, since `state` doesn't behave as I'd like (how `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` behaves).